# ASP.NET MVC System.Net.Mail embed image not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am sending an email via ASP.NET MVC 4 using System.Net.Mail and I am trying to embed an image in it like so:

```
            message = "<br/><br/><img src='/Images/cp-map.jpg' /><br/><br/>";

            MailAddress to = new MailAddress(example@email.com);
            MailAddress from = new MailAddress(“example2@email.com");
            MailMessage email = new MailMessage(from, to);
            email.Subject = “Subject”;
            email.Body = message;
            email.IsBodyHtml = true;
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("mail.email.com");
```

I get the email, but it does not have the image in it just a blue box with a question mark in it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The image url **should be an absolute url** (*a url which you can copy and paste to any browser window and you will be able to see the image*), not a relative url because when you open the email from any email provider's web app(*ex: gmail.co*m), it is trying to load the image from relative path which might not exist in gmail's web app.

This should work.

```
var imgUrl="https://www.yourSite.com/Images/cp-map.jpg";
message = "<br/><br/><img src='"+imgUrl+"' /><br/><br/>";
```

Replace `yourSite` with your actual site name or another domain where the images are hosted with the same url pattern.